# How to create a unique point of connection with MongoDB?

Tags: java, mongodb, keep-alive, mongo-java-driver

I need help for an improvement to our mongo cluster architecture currently in production on our company system.
The current situation is the following:

We have one cluster with three different replications, one primary and two secondary. 
Our applications are in Java and then we use Java Mongo Driver to create connections to MongoDB instances.
Now we pass all of these three address to MongoClient instance for create a new connection but I wonder how can I change this implementation.
I want create an architecture system like Mongo Atlas.

Mongo Atlas offers you a unique url to create a connection. 
Is like a unique server that has to receive the connection requests and forward to the mongo cluster them 
(and get the connection response and forward to the applications).

Could be represented with this diagram:

[image]

I think that "Server" check also who is the primary, if master is alive and so on..
How can I implement a similar configuration? Mongo offers some commands or service to create the Server middleware instance?

Comment: You need to replicate the public API which the driver uses and then pass the commands on. I expect many unforseen problems (do I send this command to everyone or just one Mongo instance?). That said, your whole replication will be useless when this new server fails. As it is, the driver should fallback to the replications for certain operation.

Comment: What about if I don't want share three different addresses but only one to the clients? Replica is at the end of diagram, "Server" obviously have to be in high availability.

Comment: It's still a single point of failure. If you don't want to turn off replication for some reason, the same reason probably applies to "Server". That said, you could define an API to access the data in mongo DB and force app to use this API instead of talking to the mongo DB directly. Each app could get their own server, so failures would just affect this app.

Comment: I see what do you mean and I agree.. but I want to know: how Mongo Atlas works? Why there I can use only a single point of connection? There you have two different mode to apply a connection: with a single url to the cluster and with all of the addresses of the replica set.

Comment: I found this one: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#connections-dns-seedlist
Maybe it's what I want :-)